# Word - making an object occupying more than one page

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to make a MS-Word object to occupy more than one page, also, how do I make the line numbers in that object visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible for any object in Microsoft Word to span more than one page, it's a restriction of the object model. Depending on your needs you may be able to work around this by splitting your image into separate parts or embedding only a subset of what you are trying to include.